# python code not resolve gFile from tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to run code shown below in python 3.7.5 and Tensorflow 1.15:

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
#my codes
```

but I get this error:

what is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Is that really a Python error? It looks like simply an IDE notification because the IDE is not detecting the `tensorflow` package since it was likely not installed using the IDE. Have you tried running the code to see if Python can import the package? If so you can safely ignore that message or disable notifications in your IDE for that package.

Comment: Yes! It seems that 1.13.2 supports this code but 1.15 doesn't. I'm working on it

Comment: Good idea, you can find a supporting.version. and when you find the fix put it in the answer.